# List allowed values for headnode and workernode while creating HDInsight cluster using resource manager template

Tags: azure, azure-hdinsight, adal4j

I need to load the list of possible values that can be set for headnode and workernode in the template for creating the HDInsight cluster. Is there any java API available for this? Or any other way for getting the list. Also I an unable to find any documentation that describes the list or details of the template parameters.

e.g of the template:

```
"computeProfile": {
          "roles": [
            {
              "name": "headnode",
              "targetInstanceCount": "2",
              "hardwareProfile": {
                "vmSize": "Standard_D3"
              },
              "osProfile": {
                "linuxOperatingSystemProfile": {
                  "username": "[parameters('sshUserName')]",
                  "password": "[parameters('sshPassword')]"
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "name": "workernode",
              "targetInstanceCount": "[parameters('clusterWorkerNodeCount')]",
              "hardwareProfile": {
                "vmSize": "Standard_D3"
              },
              "osProfile": {
                "linuxOperatingSystemProfile": {
                  "username": "[parameters('sshUserName')]",
                  "password": "[parameters('sshPassword')]"
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ],
```

Answer (score 0):

There is not any Java API (even REST API) which can list the possible values for headnode and workernode in the template for creating the HDInsight cluster.

The only clue is shown in the section [`Parameters`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-authoring-templates#parameters) of offical tutorial `Authoring Azure Resource Manager templates`. The `allowedValues` property as element which lists the values as you want, but not required for ARM template, as below.

[image]

So the only way for your needs is that copying these values on Azure portal when creating a HDInsight instance, or collecting these values displayed in all exsiting templates about HDInsight from [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates).

Hope it helps.